# Issue updating nginx to latest version on Windows 10 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, windows-10

I recently installed ubuntu shell on my windows 10 machine. I then installed nginx on it using apt-get install nginx. It installed the version 1.4.6 of nginx.

I need a feature that starts with nginx 1.9.5, but I can't seem to find a way to go above 1.4.6. I executed apt-cache policy nginx, and it shows me 1.4.6 is the latest version. In fact, the latest stable release of Nginx is 1.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I think, it had nothing to do with windows 10 linux shell. I did the following as mentioned on the nginx website (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/):

```
## Append the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list and replace $release with your corresponding Ubuntu release
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ $release nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ $release nginx

# Then execute the next commands
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```